# Unable to web scrape a table from CME Group's website in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape this table from CME
[image]
https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/cme-group-benchmark-administration/term-sofr.html

However the read_html or html function of xml2 and rvest respectively never return anything.
Can anyone guide how can I pull this into a R dataframe?

Comment: Wow, they're tar-pitting basic scraping. While I'm really curious, that suggests to me that they are taking active measures to prevent it. Without much diving, I suspect that they have a terms-of-use that expressly forbids doing so, even for academic purposes. Have you reached out to them? Perhaps they have an API to facilitate going straight to the data.

Comment: But if it's just that one table, this worked for me: (1) in R, paste this in but don't hit enter: `dat <- read.table(text = readLines(con="clipboard")[-1], sep="\t")`; (2) highlight the whole table, even though they have double-row headers; (3) copy (`Ctrl-C`); (4) back in R, hit enter. I know that isn't automated, but at least it keeps you from having to type things in manually :-) (The `con="clipboard"` is for windows, I think macos has something different...)

Comment: You can go via `quantmod` to Yahoo! Finance, e.g. `quantmod::getQuote(c("CL=F", "GC=F", "ES=F", "TY=F"))` gets you four front contracts.

Comment: @r2evans their root robots.txt is very restrictive!

Comment: It looks like RSelenium still works! But it's very possible if they'll block your RSelenium browser pretty quickly if you're scraping a lot of their page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still automatically scrape the table off this page if you use RSelenium. I would argue this method is much more fun than manually copying and pasting the HTML or the table's text :D
Here's how:

```
# load libraries
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

# define target url
url <- "https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/cme-group-benchmark-administration/term-sofr.html"


# start RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------------

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4550L, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

# open the remote driver-------------------------------------------------------
remDr$open()

# Navigate to webpage -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$navigate(url)


# pull the webpage html
# then read it
page_html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html()

# Find all the tables on the page
tables <- page_html %>% html_table()

# save the first table in a new variable
CME_table <- tables[[1]]
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
> CME_table
# A tibble: 6 × 10
  Date  CME T…¹ CME T…² CME T…³ CME T…⁴ Sofr …⁵ Sofr …⁶ Sofr …⁷
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 Date  1 Month 3 Month 6 Month 12 Mon… Overni… Index   30-Day…
2 04 A… 4.82805 4.93736 4.94064 4.7373  -       1.0723… 4.67186
3 03 A… 4.81043 4.92063 4.9201  4.75019 4.84    1.0721… 4.66213
4 31 M… 4.80247 4.90855 4.89968 4.73451 4.87    1.0717… 4.63004
5 30 M… 4.80341 4.89012 4.86581 4.69477 4.82    1.0716… 4.62101
6 29 M… 4.80702 4.89833 4.86464 4.6642  4.83    1.0714… 4.61164
# … with 2 more variables: `Sofr Averages *` <chr>,
#   `Sofr Averages *` <chr>, and abbreviated variable names
#   ¹​`CME Term Sofr (%)`, ²​`CME Term Sofr (%)`,
#   ³​`CME Term Sofr (%)`, ⁴​`CME Term Sofr (%)`, ⁵​`Sofr *`,
#   ⁶​`Sofr *`, ⁷​`Sofr Averages *`
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Some caveats to this approach:

1. RSelenium can sometime be a bit tricky sometimes to set up.
2. This page doesn't want to be scraped, so if you're scraping a lot from their site, I would take steps to avoid getting blocked such as adding delays into your code, adding random key and mouse movements, and specifying a different user agent.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the webpage and then read the html file in using `read_html` you can inspect the webpage to find the location (the Xpath) of the table and use that info with `html_element` and `html_table` to get the data.

[image: Finding the location of the table]

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("Term SOFR - CME Group.html")
xpath <- '//*[@id="main-content"]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/table'
page %>% 
  html_element(xpath = xpath) %>% 
  html_table()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 10
#>   Date   CME T…¹ CME T…² CME T…³ CME T…⁴ Sofr …⁵ Sofr …⁶ Sofr …⁷ Sofr …⁸ Sofr …⁹
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 Date   1 Month 3 Month 6 Month 12 Mon… Overni… Index   30-Day… 90-Day… 180-Da…
#> 2 04 Ap… 4.82805 4.93736 4.94064 4.7373  -       1.0723… 4.67186 4.53349 4.13336
#> 3 03 Ap… 4.81043 4.92063 4.9201  4.75019 4.84    1.0721… 4.66213 4.52753 4.12316
#> 4 31 Ma… 4.80247 4.90855 4.89968 4.73451 4.87    1.0717… 4.63004 4.50833 4.09148
#> 5 30 Ma… 4.80341 4.89012 4.86581 4.69477 4.82    1.0716… 4.62101 4.50247 4.08105
#> 6 29 Ma… 4.80702 4.89833 4.86464 4.6642  4.83    1.0714… 4.61164 4.49651 4.07056
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​`CME Term Sofr (%)`, ²​`CME Term Sofr (%)`,
#> #   ³​`CME Term Sofr (%)`, ⁴​`CME Term Sofr (%)`, ⁵​`Sofr *`, ⁶​`Sofr *`,
#> #   ⁷​`Sofr Averages *`, ⁸​`Sofr Averages *`, ⁹​`Sofr Averages *`
```

Comment: thank you very much victor! I was able to achieve this after downloading the page and running your code. 
One question - did you manually save that page from browser or did you use some function to download it? And is latter possible?

Comment: I downloaded the html manually. As others have mentioned this website has protections that prevent from the usual scraping process. It may take additional steps to scrape if possible. I am sure there is some workaround but I don't know it.